# (python) How to convert long into raw string?

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that can do integer to raw string conversion, but it does not take long. Any solutions?

```
def intToBytes(integer):
  hex_form = hex(integer)[2:]; # 2: gets rid of leading 0x
  if (len(hex_form) % 2):
    hex_form = '0' + hex_form;
  return bytearray.fromhex(hex_form)
```

Comment: How do you want ints >= 2^64 to be handled?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann, I thought the biggest python2.7 int is 2^63-1

Comment: Looks like long/int cutoff is 2^31 -1 on my system, but what I meant was how do you want > 64-bit longs handled. Lots of other languages don't handle variable precision ints very well and would rather you stick to 64-bit ints. And then there's Javascript.

Comment: It looks like the solution given by 6502 works for long type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the ending `'L'` when present:

```
def intToBytes(integer):
    hex_form = hex(integer)[2:]; # 2: gets rid of leading 0x
    if hex_form[-1:] == 'L':
        # Remove final `L` from arbitrary precision integers
        hex_form = hex_form[:-1]
    if (len(hex_form) % 2):
        hex_form = '0' + hex_form;
    return bytearray.fromhex(hex_form)
```